# While Loop Macro in DrRacket

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

I am trying to create a macro for while loop in DrRacket. Here is what I wrote:

```
(require mzlib/defmacro)

(define-macro my-while
  (lambda (condition  body)
    (list 'local (list (list 'define (list 'while-loop)
                             (list 'if condition
                                   (list body (list 'while-loop))
                                   '(void))))
          '(while-loop))))


(define x 0)

(my-while (< x 10)
          (begin              
            (display x)
            (newline)
            (set! x (+ x 1))))
```

The output of this program is:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
error:  procedure application: expected procedure, given: #<void>; arguments were: #<void>
```

Can someone help me with this? Why wouldn't this macro just terminate and return void. It seems that when the **condition** is not true, the system tries to apply the void as an argument to some procedure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ouch:

1. Using this style of `while` loop encourages excessive use of imperative programming.
2. Using `define-macro` creates unhygienic macros, which is a nightmare in Scheme.

While I don't encourage writing an imperative-style loop macro, for your reference, here's a non-`define-macro` version of the same macro:

```
(define-syntax-rule (my-while condition body ...)
  (let loop ()
    (when condition
      body ...
      (loop))))
```

It uses `syntax-rules`, which creates hygienic macros, and is much, much easier to read than what you have.

---

Now, for the actual answer for your question, first, let's write your original macro out in a more readable way:

```
(define-macro my-while
  (lambda (condition body)
    `(local ((define (while-loop)
               (if ,condition
                   (,body (while-loop))
                   (void))))
       (while-loop))))
```

Once you write it out this way, you can see where the real problem is: in the `(,body (while-loop))` line, which should instead have been `(begin ,body (while-loop))`.

Comment: True and True. But I have just seen a macro for the first time in my life today (in Teach Yourself Scheme in Fixnum Days). Still learning. I haven't read about hygienic macros yet.

Comment: @RajeshBhat: Also, I've just updated my answer with the explanation of why your unhygienic macro isn't working. :-) But I still encourage you to use the hygienic version, of course. ;-)

Comment: @RajeshBhat Macros are a wortwhile study. Scheme in a Fixnum Days is good, but the section on macros is outdated. If I were you I'd find an introduction on macros using either syntax-rules or syntax-case. I can recommend the introduction in the Racket Guide: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/pattern-macros.html

Answer (score 2):

Another version of while uses a do loop:

```
(define-syntax while
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((while pred? stmt ...)
      (do () ((not pred?))
        stmt ...))))
```

Comment: That does indeed work, though a `do` loop usually macro-expands to a named-`let`-based loop anyway, and many Schemers tell me that named `let` loops are much more idiomatic than `do` loops, which are more...CL-style. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Why use a macro when a plain old function will do?

```
;; fun-while : (-> Boolean) (-> Any) -> Void
(define (fun-while condition body)
  (when (condition)
    (body)
    (fun-while condition body))
```

Of course, this requires you to pass in repeatable actions that can be called (this is why `condition` and `body` are surrounded with parens in the body of `fun-while`), so you do need a macro if you want prettier syntax. But once you have a function that has the desired behavior, putting some sugar on top is trivial for this case:

```
(define-syntax-rule (my-while condition body ...)
   (fun-while (lambda () condition)
              (lambda () body ...)))
```

Now, as has been said, this encourages imperative style, which is frowned upon. Instead of mutation, try making the state explicit instead:

```
;; pure-while : forall State.
;;    (State -> Boolean)   ; the "condition" that inspects the state
;;    (State -> State)     ; the "body" that moves from one state to the next
;;    ->   ; curried
;;    State                ; the current state
;; -> State                ; produces the ending state
(define ((pure-while condition make-next) current-state)
   (if (condition current-state)
       (pure-while condition make-next (make-next current-state))
       current-state))
```

You'll notice that the first two arguments are now functions from `State` to something, and the result of applying to 2 arguments is also a function from `State -> State`. This is a recurring pattern that, as a Haskeller, I'd call the "State Monad". Discussion of putting sugar on top of this concept is a little beyond the scope of this conversation, though, so I'll just stop there.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's been a while:

a `while` macro for Racket 6.0

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax while
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ pred? stmt ...)
     (do () ((not pred?))
      stmt ...))))
```