# How to find a list of all functions in a Racket module?

Tags: module, racket

I know I can read the documentation, but because that requires switching my attention away from my editor and the REPL, I'd like to be able to see a list of functions provided the modules I am using.

Is there something in Racket analogous to Ruby's `Foo.methods()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function [`module->exports`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Module_Names_and_Loading.html?q=module-%3Eexports&q=seconds-&q=file%20date%20modify&q=ch/wa&q=patch-lift&q=raw&q=serve/ser&q=serve/ser&q=%23%3Amanager#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._module-~3eexports%29%29) provides a list of names from a module [`provide`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html?q=provide&q=module-%3Eexports&q=seconds-&q=file%20date%20modify&q=ch/wa&q=patch-lift&q=raw&q=serve/ser&q=serve/ser&q=%23%3Amanager#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._provide%29%29) expression.

```
> (require racket/date)
> (module->exports 'racket/date) ;module name is passed not the module
'()
'((0
   (julian/scalinger->string ())
   (date->julian/scalinger ())
   (find-seconds ())
   (date-display-format ())
   (date->string ())
   (date*->seconds ())
   (date->seconds ())
   (current-date ())))
```

reference: [racket discussion list](http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2014-June/062953.html)

Because `module->exports` returns two values, `define-values` is needed to capture the list of functions and the list of macros for use elsewhere:

```
; my-module.rkt
#lang racket 
(provide (all-defined-out))
(define-syntax while
  #|
    Macros do not allow documentation strings
    While macro from StackOverflow.
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968212/while-loop-macro-in-drracket
    |#
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ pred? stmt ...)
     (do () ((not pred?))
       stmt ...))))

(define my-const 9)

(define (prn a)
"Prints the passed value on a new line"
  (printf "\n~a" a))

(define (my-func a)
"Another documentation string"
  (prn a))
```

Referenced in:

```
;some-other-file.rkt
#lang racket
(require "my-module.rkt")
(define-values (functions-and-constants macros)
  (module->exports '"my-module.rkt"))
```

In REPL:

```
> functions-and-constants
'((0 (my-const ()) (my-func ()) (prn ())))
> macros
'((0 (while ())))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`xrepl`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/xrepl/index.html), you can use the `describe` command to get more usefully formatted information:

```
Welcome to Racket v6.1.0.3.
-> ,describe racket/date
; `racket/date' is a module,
;   located at <collects>/racket/date.rkt
;   imports: <collects>/racket/base.rkt, <collects>/racket/contract/base.rkt,
;     <collects>/racket/promise.rkt.
;   direct syntax exports: current-date, date*->seconds,
;     date->julian/scalinger, date->seconds, date->string, date-display-format,
;     find-seconds, julian/scalinger->string.
```

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. It's more analogous to an IRB context because xrepl is not available withing a program. I've added a programmatic use example to my answer.