# Using break from loop in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I can use "while" loop in Racket with code from [While Loop Macro in DrRacket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968212/while-loop-macro-in-drracket)

```
(define-syntax-rule (while-loop condition body ...)   
  (let loop ()
    (when condition
      body ...
      (loop))))
```

However, I want to use break inside an infinite loop as follows:

```
(define (testfn)
  (define x 5)
  (while-loop #t          ; infinite while loop; 
    (println x)
    (set! x (sub1 x))
    (when (< x 0)
       (break))))         ; HOW TO BREAK HERE;
```

How can I insert break in above indefinite while loop? Thanks for your comments/answers.

Comment: The code in the question uses an imperative style, this is not how we write a loop in Scheme.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't. Racket is in the Scheme family so all loops are actually done with recursion.

You break out of a loop by not recursing. Any other value would become the result of the form.

```
(define (helper x) 
  (displayln x) 
  (if (< x 0)
      'return-value
      (helper (sub1 x))) 
(helper 5)
```

There are macros that makes the syntax simpler. Using named `let` is one:

```
(let helper ((x 5))
  (displayln x) 
  (if (< x 0)
      'return-value
      (helper (sub1 x)))
```

Looking at your `while-loop` is just a macro that uses named `let` macro that turns into a recursive procedure.

If you instead of `#t` write an expression that eventually becomes false it stops. Like:

```
(while-loop (<= 0 x)
  ...)
```

Note that using `set!` to update variables in a loop is not considered good practise. If you are learning Racket try not to use `set!` or your new looping construct. Try using named `let` or `letrec`.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the accepted answer to the linked question, it's *not* recommended - at all! to do looping in this fashion. When using standard Scheme avoid imperative loops and prefer recursion (using helper procedures or a named `let`), or use [iterations and comprehensions](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html) in Racket.

Also, `break` is not a standard Scheme construct. Consider rewriting the logic using a more idiomatic Racket that doesn't require explicit breaking and avoids the imperative style:

```
(define (testfn n)
  (for [(x (in-range n -1 -1))]
    (println x)))

(testfn 5)
=> 5
   4
   3
   2
   1
   0
```