# The While Loop in Racket

Tags: loops, while-loop, scheme, conditional-statements, racket

Write a procedure in Racket that act like the "while loops" in languages like Java.  A while loop takes two pieces of code to run: a condition and a body.  it runs the body, then tries the condition again, running the body again if it's true.  This continues until the condition returns false.

this is how I started on it: then I got stuck.

```
(define (while condition body)
   (when (true? condition)
       (cons (proc body) (proc (rest body)))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [While Loop Macro in DrRacket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968212/while-loop-macro-in-drracket)

Answer (score 2):

`condition` and `body` are procedures, so you have have to call them.

After calling the body, you have to call `while` recursively to repeat.

```
(define (while condition body)
  (when (condition)
    (body)
    (while condition body)))
```

You don't need `true?`, since `when` just checks whether the condition is `#f` or not.

Answer (score 1):

in Scheme while must be implemented with macro to avoid evaluation of args

```
(define-syntax while
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ pred b1 ...)
     (let loop () (when pred b1 ... (loop))))))
```

Comment: OP was asked to write a procedure, not a macro; in this case `condition` and `body` represent procedures, i.e., they evaluate to procedures which are to be used within `while`.

Comment: ok thanks. but you can not do a real While or Do with procedure, unless as you say condition and body evaluates to procedure. But i do not really see the use it can be done. The original question was about java like while, for making the same thing in scheme it is with macro.