# Trouble with implementing a while loop in an interpreter in Racket

Tags: while-loop, scheme, racket, interpreter

I am very new to working with Racket. I need my interpreter to correctly identify the following statement and execute the "while" loop.

```
(= x 10)
    (while (> x 0) ((print x)(= x (- x 1))))))
```

Currently, my implementation of a while loop is throwing an error I don't entirely understand.
My partial implementation is as follows:

```
(define interp
  (lambda (stmt myEnv)
       (cond
    ((eqv? (car stmt) 'print) (begin
                                (display "\n")
                                (display (exp myEnv (cadr stmt)))
                                myEnv))
    ((eqv? (car stmt) '=) (extend-env myEnv (cadr stmt)(exp myEnv (caddr stmt))))
    ((eqv? (car stmt) 'while) (while myEnv (cadr stmt)))

(define (while cond body)
  (when (cond)
    (display "x")
    (while cond body)))
```

I'm getting an error that says:

```
    application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '(extend-env x 10 (empty-env))
```

Which leads me to believe I am fatally misunderstanding a key component of how Racket processes functions. Could someone explain what my misstep may be, and how I could go about fixing this definition? A large portion of this skeleton code has been provided for me, so if possible I would like to get the while definition working without modifying anything other than the while definition and the line where I am passing the variables and calling the while definition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [While Loop Macro in DrRacket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968212/while-loop-macro-in-drracket)

Comment: You're trying to apply an environment as if it were a procedure.

Comment: I think you're either missing the point of the interpreter or confusing your language with the implementation language. Your `while` needs to interpret the condition and the body in the given environment.