# Find the longest integer in a vector using while loops

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, integer, racket

Working on this program that's supposed to take a vector of integers as input and return the one with the longest integer. Example (vector 20 738 5942 125) and would return 4 as its the longest one. I'm pretty sure I have most of this done the only issue I have is in the conditional as I have to call an outside function (count-integers), this is what I have so far:

```
(require while)
(define (empty-VINT? low high) (> low high))


(define (count-integers n)
  (cond [(< n 10) 1] 
        (else(+ 1 (count-integers [/ n 10])))))

(define (count-digits V)
  (local [
          (define x (void))
          (define accum (void))
          (define largest 0)]
           
          (begin
            (set! x (vector-length V))
            (set! accum 0)
            (while (< accum (vector-length V))
                   (cond [(empty-VINT? x accum) accum]
                         [(> (count-integers (vector-ref V accum) largest)
                             (add1 x) accum(vector-ref V accum))]
                         [else add1 accum])))))
```

Right now when its run, I get this message: cond: expected a clause with a question and an answer, but found a clause with only one part. Any suggestions would be great, thanks

Comment: Naming things according to what they do (or are intended to do) should help: right now, `count-integers` doesn't "count integers", `count-digits` isn't for "counting digits", `accum` isn't an accumulator. Also parentheses misplaced.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize that my function names didn't make sense till now but how come accum isn't an accumulator? I figured that's the parameter I was using in order to stop the loop as it accumulates 1 for each iteration the loop goes through to my understanding at least to my understanding of it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not clear what do you want to return. `4` isn't *the longest integer* (that's `5942`), `4` is *a maximal digit count among integers in given vector*.

Secondly, your code isn't idiomatic and without your comment, it's very hard to say what's going on. Programming in functional languages requies functional way of thinking. Forget about `while`, `set!`, `void`, `local` and nested `define` and instead spend some time learning about [`apply`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29), [`map`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29), [`filter`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29) and [`foldl`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29).

I would solve this problem like this:

```
(define (digits number)
  (string-length (number->string number)))

(define (max-digit-count vec)
  (apply max (map digits (vector->list vec))))

(max-digit-count (vector 20 738 5942 125))
=> 4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this helps and yeah I understand this isn't idiomatic. I approached this problem this way since I've been being taught to use mutators, recursion (which I already solved for this problem) and while loops as that's what I've been told to use all semester. The problem states: Design and implement a function to find the number of digits in the longest integer in a (vectorof integer) hence why I would want to return 4 in the example.

Answer (score 0):

@MartinPuda's answer is quite good.

I would have defined:

```
(define (digits n (acc 0)) 
  (if (< n 1) 
      acc
      (digits (/ n 10) (+ acc 1))))

(define (max-digits lst) 
  (digits (car (sort lst >))))
```

To apply it:

```
(max-digits (vector->list (vector 20 738 5942 125)))
```

#### Why you should not use `while`

Using `while` would force you to mutate variable values. It is much more "natural" for lisp languages to follow the functional style (recursive functions instead of `while` loops or other loops) rather than the imperative style with mutation of variables.

That is why `while` is not in the lisp languages.

But if you want to use it:

```
(define-syntax-rule (while condition body ...)
  ;; From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968212/while-loop-macro-in-drracket
  (let loop ()
    (when condition
      body ...
      (loop))))

(define (digits n (acc 0)) 
  (cond ((< n 1) acc) 
        (else (digits (/ n 10) (+ acc 1)))))

(define (max-digits lst)
  (let ((max-digit 0))
    (while (not (null? lst))
      (let ((digit (digits (car lst))))
        (when (< max-digit digit)
          (set! max-digit digit))
        (set! lst (cdr lst))))
     max-digit))
```

Then you can try:

```
> (max-digits (vector->list v))
4
> (max-digits '(1111 123456  2345 34))
6
```

#### Prefer `let` over `define`

Why? Because if you use `let`, you can control the scope of the to-be-mutated variable very precisely. You can define in your definition, from where on your variable canNOT have any effect on your code (since its scope ended at some point). While with `define` you don't have this fine-grained control. (Or this control is implicit not explicite like with `let`). You could delete/unbind the variable explicitely but that is rarely done in real life.

Therefore, in Lisp, for variable declarations use whenever possible `let`, especially whenever you deal with mutated variables.

All imperative `=` declarations should be in Lisp languages `let` expressions!

#### You can use function arguments instead of `let`-definitions, because they are anyway implemented using `let`s

Just you save syntactically some lines - and the fewer lines you occupy the cleaner the code.

```
#lang racket

(define (digits n)
  (string-length (number->string n)))

(define (max-digit a b)
  (if (< (digits a) (digits b)) b a))

(define (max-digits lst (res ""))
  (while (not (null? lst))
     (set! res (max-digit res (car lst)))
     (set! lst (cdr lst)))
  (digits res))
```

Comment: Thanks, I know using while in this case isn't ideal but I approached it this way as that's the requirement for this as I've been taught about mutators, while loops, generative/accumulative recursion. I already solved this problem using recursion and wanted to have it both ways with while as well hence why I designed it this way. Hope this clears things up, thanks again for your answer it helps

Comment: Welcome @Dima - that said, mutation per se is not bad. Bad is only the wrong usage of mutation. Used properly and safely, mutation helps to gain speed and narrow the memory footprint.

Comment: It helps e.g. to wrap around the sections where mutation happens a `let`-form `(let ((to-be-mutated-var initial-value)) ...where-mutation-happens...)` - by that, the mutation and its effect is restricted only to this special area of the code. `let` used in this way is very powerful in dam up mutations and their potentially detrimental effects on the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

From comments:

> Design and implement a function to find the number of digits in the longest integer in a (vectorof integer) ...
> use ... while loops

So a plan (*design*) might be:

> count-digits: integer -> natural
> max-digit-count: (vectorof integer) -> natural
> ..something **while** something **max** **count-digits** something ???

*Implementing* `count-digits` seems straightforward (but
integers can be negative, and in Racket `(integer? 123.000)` is true).

```
#lang racket

(define (count-digits int) ;; Integer -> Natural
  ;; produce count of digits in int
  (string-length (number->string (abs (exact-truncate int)))))
```

As @Gwang-Jin Kim mentions, `while` could be defined:

```
(define-syntax-rule (while condition body ...)
  ;; From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968212/while-loop-macro-in-drracket
  (let loop ()
    (when condition
      body ...
      (loop))))
```

and then one could use it:

```
(define (max-digit-count vec) ;; VectorOfInteger -> Natural
  ;; produce maximum of digit counts of vec elements
  (define vx  0)
  (define acc 0)
  (while (< vx (vector-length vec))
         (set! acc (max accum (count-digits (vector-ref vec vx))))
         (set! vx (add1 vx)))
  acc)
```

`(max-digit-count (vector 20 -738.00 5942 125)) ;=> 4`

One of the problems with `while` is that it can't produce a value (where would it come
from if the condition is false on entry?)

If one "enhanced" `while` a bit:

```
(define-syntax-rule (while< x-id limit a-id a-init update)
  ;; "while loop" incrementing x-id from 0 to limit-1, updating a-id 
  (let loop ([x-id 0] [a-id a-init])
    (if (< x-id limit)
      (loop (add1 x-id) update)
      a-id)))
```

`max-digit-count` could be neater:

```
(define (max-digit-count vec) ;; VectorOfInteger -> Natural
  ;; produce maximum of digit counts of vec elements
  (while< vx (vector-length vec)
          acc 0 (max acc (count-digits (vector-ref vec vx)))))
```